# npm package chalk is not working with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, chalk, cypress-task

I want to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk for console logs.

Now if I use with `console.log` it works

`console.log(chalk.blue("Hello World"))`

but when I run it with cy.task it doesn't give any error but doesn't show any coloring

`cy.task('log', chalk.blue("Hello World"));` it prints Hello World but not in blue color

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Chalk is based on ANSI-standard escape sequences for terminals (real ones and virtual ones). If you send the strings Chalk builds to a terminal (that correctly interprets the codes), then it works. If you add the strings to HTML content, they won't work.

Comment: @Pointy I am using mac terminal and iterm2, it should work on these right?

Comment: Yes, however I don't know what Cypress does with those strings you pass through. (I'm also on MacOS.)

Answer (score 5):

The Cypress `cy.task()` command is an interprocess communication (browser to nodejs) and it must serialize it's parameters.

I guess, from the result of your test,  that means the ansi chars used to color the log entry might be stripped away.

One way to get around that is to invoke `chalk` inside the task.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'
import chalk from 'chalk';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('task', {
        log({message, attributes}) {
          const fn = attributes.reduce((chalk, attr) => chalk[attr], chalk)
          console.log(fn(message))
          return null;
        },
      });

      return config;
    },
  },
});
```

Since `chalk` v5 is pure ESM, I had to convert the `cypress.config.js` to the ESM format given for typescript on this page [Configuration File](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration) and add `"type": "module",` to the package.json, although the docs say you could also use the `mjs` extension.

This is the test

```js
it('logs to terminal using chalk', () => {
  cy.task('log', {message: 'hello chalk', attributes: ['underline', 'bgBlue', 'bold', 'green']})
})
```

This is the output

[image]

Comment: It is failing to recognize `reduce`, and gives this error. `> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')`

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to bracket the arguments - `cy.task` can only take one argument, so you have to bracket them the same as I have (both in the test and in the task).

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting which one you are referring. Can you highlight in your answer?

Comment: Yes, when you call `cy.task('log', message, attributes)`, only the `message` parameter is passed to the task - the `attributes` parameter is dropped hence the error message you received. See [task#Arguments](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Arguments) - ***If you need to pass multiple arguments, use an object***.

Comment: So the call should be `cy.task('log', {message: 'hello chalk', attributes: [...]})` instead of  `cy.task('log', 'hello chalk', [...])`

Comment: And inside the task you also need brackets `log({message, attributes})`

Comment: I tried copy-pasting the code that you shared, but still it is giving the error. Can you please check? I have uploaded the code here. https://github.com/foobarMintQA/testChalk

Comment: I ran your repo, it worked! Had to clean up all that bother with the cypress config file(s).

Comment: Can you share the config file in your answer? or PR Commit in the repo?